# Find a projective change of coordinates

Tags: conic-sections, coordinate-systems, projective-geometry

Find a projective change of coordinates that takes the projective completion of the circumference C:    $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ to the projective completion of the parabola P:  $y^2=2px$, $p \geq 0$

> (i.e. $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ to $y^2=2pxz$)

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1273662/265466.

Comment: I don’t get the explanation there, it becomes the regular circumference, not its completion.

Comment: It's a change of variables in homogeneous coordinates. You can find the point on the circle that corresponds to the point at infinity $(1, 0, 0)$ on the parabola.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer I found myself works as my professor checked it. The answer is in Spanish but I feel it's pretty easy to understand.

[image]